# Why Apache Beam's Spark runner giving error Error: Failed to load org/apache/beam/sdk/options/PipelineOptions?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-beam

I tried to run a working Apache Beam code with Spark-Runner using command

```
spark-submit --class org.apache.beam.examples.WordCount --master spark://localhost:4040 target\word-count-beam-0.1.jar
--runner=SparkRunner
```

but it throws error

```
Error: Failed to load org.apache.beam.examples.WordCount: org/apache/beam/sdk/options/PipelineOptions
22/04/29 12:59:54 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
22/04/29 12:59:54 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory C:\Users\Mohit\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-8f8164aa-816e-4d96-96d0-f1ec7441d4a8
```

This first line in above error this is the problem.
I am just trying to run normal example of WordCount that Apache Beam gives. Do anybody have an idea?

Comment: Can you provide the full error message?

Comment: This is the only message

Comment: How is the jar built?